# Java http GET keeps getting a null

Tags: java

I am able to perform this GET command successfully in Postman which returns various headers that I need.  I use basic auth for this first GET:

GET http://SERVER/qcbin/api/authentication/sign-in

I'm trying to implement this in Java but nothing is coming back. I keep getting a null.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I can't figure out my mistake.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Base64;


public class test2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("myproxy", 8080));
        URL url = new URL ("http://SERVER/qcbin/api/authentication/sign-in");  

        byte[] credBytes = ("jsmith" + ":" + "abc123").getBytes();

        Base64.Encoder base64Encoder = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding();
        String encoding = base64Encoder.encodeToString(credBytes);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
```

content is set to null after the following line.

```
        InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in   = 
            new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you do your postman test on the machine the java code is ran? Can you post a `curl -vvv` of your request?

Comment: Why do you call `setDoOutput(true)`? Doesn't the connection expect some output in this case first?

Comment: @RC - Yes, same machine.  I'm VERY new to java.  I'm unfamiliar with curl.

Comment: @StefanHaustein - Honestly, I don't know.  This is my first http GET via Java.  I'm trying to put this together for the first time.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Is there a firewall between you and `SERVER`? Postman would obey your proxy settings but Java would be ignorant of them...

Comment: What happens if you remove `setDoOutput(true)`?

Comment: @StefanHaustein - I tried removing it but I get the same exception.

Comment: @dcsohl - That's a good point.  I'll try setting up a proxy in Java and see if that helps.

Comment: @dcsohl - I actually have a proxy set up in eclipse.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Your code will not get that proxy setting. You have to do it separately. (Source: personal experience)

Comment: @dcsohl - can you recommend a stackoverflow page that has a good example?  I'm searching and finding too many examples that are all totally different.

Comment: I have added a proxy, I think.  I no longer get an exception but the variable, "content" is now equal to null.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code you are reading a line from the stream:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Could it be that you never get an "New of line" character from your stream meaning the server doesn't send you a data that ends with a new line character? And so when there is no more data coming through your stream the `in.readLine()` is still waiting for that End of line character?

Try replacing that code with:

```
     // reads to the end of the stream 
     while((value = br.read()) != -1)
     {
        // converts int to character
        char c = (char)value;

        // prints character
        System.out.println(c);
     }
```

Edit: From the BufferedReader javadoc:

> public String readLine()
>                   throws IOException Reads a line of text.
>
> A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a
>   carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a
>   linefeed.
>
> Returns: A String containing the contents of the line, not
>   including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the
>   stream has been reached

Comment: This can't be the problem -- readLine() will return null when the end of the stream is reached in any case.

Comment: Sure, given that the stream is flushed and closed